# jQuery next() does not find find element or return console.log()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs with the same name. The first one contains a link the user can click to get to a new page, and a dropdown-arrow to open up the next div which holds more anchor tags. It looks like this:

```
<div class="container-div">
    <a class="link-1">Men</a>
    <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
</div>
<div class="container-div">
  <a class="link-2">Featured</a>
  <a class="link-2">Sale</a>
</div>
```

As it works now, when the user clicks the span.dropdown-arrow, the second container div opens revealing the .link-2 links. When the user clicks the Men link (a.link-1), it also opens up the second container div and also takes the user to a new page. I would like it so that when the user clicks ".link-1", the second container div does not open (remains as display:none).

Here is my jQuery:

```
 function mobileMainNav(){

        $('a.link-1').click(function(){
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
        }); 

        $('a.link-1').click(function(){
            var showNone = $(this).parent().next('div.container-div').css('display', 'none');
            console.log(showNone);
        }); 
    };
```

The first part of this function works, taking the user to the new window. But the second part does not work at all, and nothing is logged in the console either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Neither part of the function should work, as your class is `link-1` rather than `level-1`. Also, you don't appear to have a `direct` class. Is this added dynamically?

Comment: Hi, Paste your html code

Comment: @ObsidianAge sorry that was a typo. It matches in my code, just fixed it here.

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda my html code is there.

Comment: instead of doing `.css()` you can just add/remove(`.addClass() and .removeClass`) class that does the hiding and showing its much cleaner to look at

Comment: well what do you expect when you change the location of the page in the first click? Page navigates away and the other click is not going to run.

Comment: @epascarello when the user clicks on "link-1", yes i want the page to navigate away but i do not want the second drop down to open - which it is. that's what i'm trying to stop.

Answer (score 0):

So call stopImmediatePropagation but it is only going to work if the events are attached in the correct order.

```js
$("button").on("click", function (e) {
  console.log(1);
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
});
$("button").on("click", function (e) {
  console.log(2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>a</button>
```